# How Can I Grab The "COUNT" From A Correlated Subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a query that looks like..

```
SELECT id_b FROM id_table
WHERE id_a = ?
AND (
       SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowCount FROM other_table
       WHERE id = id_b
     )  > 0;
```

How would I retrieve the value rowCount?

EDIT: This is a MYSQL DB

Comment: What type of database is this?

Comment: Mysql.. edited question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select A..., Z.RowCount
From id_table As A
    Cross Join  (
                Select Count(*) As RowCount
                From other_table
                Where id_b = ?
                ) As Z
Where A.id_a = ?
    And Z.RowCount > 0
```

**Edit**

Given your edit, I'm guessing you are trying achieve something akin to:

```
Select A..., Z.RowCount
From id_table As A
    Join    (
            Select id_b, Count(*) As RowCount
            From other_table
            Group By id_b
            ) As Z
        On Z.id_b = A.id_b
Where A.id_a = ?
    And Z.Cnt > 0
```

Comment: It seems as though id_b is undefined here...  "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id_b' in 'where clause'"

Comment: @HowardZoopaloopa - `id_b` is in your original query. Thus, it must exist in `other_table`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I phrased the question poorly then.. I'll make an edit.  It should be WHERE other_table_id = id_b (the result from the initial query)

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time here... I think the key here is that other_table does not have a column id_b but it has a column id that would match id_b.  So, I'm looking to count the number of rows in other_table that have an id that is equal to id_b (the result of the super-select).

Comment: I think I know how to use your answer this way... it's where A.id_b = Z.id

Comment: @HowardZoopaloopa - Correct. Here I assumed we're matching a column named `id_b` in both tables. However, it isn't much of stretch to find the equivalent if the `other_table` column is simply named something else. Either way, the assumption is that there is a correlating column(s) between `id_table` and `other_table`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
SELECT (
       SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowCount FROM other_table
       WHERE id_b = ?
     ) AS rowCount, id_b FROM id_table
WHERE id_a = ?
AND (
       SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowCount FROM other_table
       WHERE id_b = ?
     )  > 0;
```

That would work in SQL Server